# What do I do to remove (or avoid returning altogether) "None" at the end of this recursive function

Tags: python

`char_complement` looks at the index of a character in "input" and returns the letter in the same index in "output". If a letter isn't in the list, a blank is returned.

`string_complement` is supposed to do similar, but for numerous characters.

```
def char_complement(c):
    input=["A","T","C","G"]
    output=["T","A","G","C"]
    
    if c in input:
      x= input.index(c)
      return output[x]
    return ""

def string_complement(s):
    while s!="":
        return char_complement(s[0])+str(string_complement(s[1:]))
```

If s is `"ATTAGTC"`, `"TAATCAGNone"` is returned.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `while` loop here? You `return` immediately so this loop can never iterate more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `return ""` to the end of your function, so that when the `while` loop ends, and empty string is returned as opposed to `None`:

```
def string_complement(s):
    while s!="":
        return char_complement(s[0])+str(string_complement(s[1:]))
    return ""
```

Altogether:

```
def char_complement(c):
    input=["A","T","C","G"]
    output=["T","A","G","C"]
    if c in input:
      x= input.index(c)
      return output[x]
    return ""

def string_complement(s):
    while s!="":
        return char_complement(s[0])+str(string_complement(s[1:]))
    return ""

print(string_complement("ATTAGTC"))
```

Output:

```
TAATCAG
```

Answer (score 1):

as other users says: you need a `return ""` in `string_complement` function at the end

Here i had some time to play with the problem. I was thinking that Recursion is an elegant way to solve problems, but in python there's an annoying problem: RecursionError (it raises when you get to recursion lvl 3000 by default and it can be set*). I've thinked that there is better solutions than using a function to traslate every char. So I decided to try with a dictionary to solve that. And suposing that you need to translate long strings combination I proposed other methods.
I came up with 4 diferent methods to try:

```
#recursive + auxFunction
#original proposed method
def char_complement(c): 
    input=["A","T","C","G"]
    output=["T","A","G","C"]
    
    if c in input:
      x= input.index(c)
      return output[x]
    return ""

def string_complement(s):
    while s!="":
        return char_complement(s[0])+str(string_complement(s[1:]))
    return ""


#recursive + dict
def string_complement2(s):
    char_comp ={'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}
    while s!="":
        return char_comp[s[0]] + string_complement2(s[1:])
    return ""

#comprehension + dict
def string_complement3(s):
    char_comp ={'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}
    return [char_comp[thisS] for thisS in s]

# for + dict
def string_complement4(s):
    char_comp ={'A':'T','T':'A','C':'G','G':'C'}
    complement = ""
    for thisS in s:
        complement += char_comp[thisS]
    return complement
```

for last i only have to test all the methods and compare execution times. so I proposed this (maybe time isn't the best library to measure time between excecutions idk):

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
def test_and_get_times(n):
    #generate seq
    atcgList = ['A','T','C','G']
    seq = ''.join( np.random.choice(atcgList,n))
    
    try : #to avoid RecursionError
        t1 = time()
        a1 = string_complement(seq)
        t2 = time() 
        a2 = string_complement2(seq)
        t3 = time()
    except RecursionError: #if RecursionError set values to nan
        t2=np.nan
        t3=np.nan
    finally:
        t4 = time()
        a3 = string_complement3(seq)
        t5 = time()
        a4 = string_complement4(seq)
        t6 = time()

    return [t2-t1,t3-t2,t5-t4,t6-t5]


#diferent lengths to test methods
nList = np.arange(10,10001,111)

#test all lengths
times = np.zeros([4,len(nList)])
for i,n in enumerate(nList):
    times[:,i] = test_and_get_times(n)


#plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot(nList,times[0],label='Recursive + auxFunc')
plt.plot(nList,times[1],label='Recursive + auxDic')
plt.plot(nList,times[2],label='Comprehension+ auxDic')
plt.plot(nList,times[3],label='For + auxDic')
plt.legend()
```

run the code and get results:

[image: run times]

Conclusion seems that using a dictionary to get the complements is faster than creating an auxiliary function for the same thing. Using for-comprehension or simply a for avoids the RecursionError. and let run largers sequencies

Sorry for my potato english ( i might have a lot of errors semantics and sintactics)

hope this can help you in some way!
cheers!

*to set another value to recursion Limit:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(desiredValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to use recursion? This can be easily done with indexes:

```
INPUT = ["A","T","C","G"]
OUTPUT = ["T","A","G","C"]

def get_complement(str_in):
    letters = list(str_in)
    return ''.join(
        [
            OUTPUT[INPUT.index(letter)]
            for letter in letters
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by a one-line declaration and two one-line functions:

```
COMPLEMENTS = dict(A='T', T='A', C='G', G='C')

def char_complement(c):
    return COMPLEMENTS.get(c, "")

def string_complement(s):
    return ''.join([char_complement(c) for c in s])

print(string_complement("ATTAGTC"))

>>>TAATCAG
```